# YouTube API - setModerationStatus to heldForReview not working

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api, google-apis-explorer

I have tried several times for the past few hours to deal with this but i think it's related to the YouTube Api or some other restriction in place.

I am currently moderating multiple yt channels' comments section through YT API and setting malicious comments in "heldForReview" status if they match specific criterias (scam/spam type of comments)

Since few hours ago i keep receiving the following error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "The API server failed to successfully process the request. While this can be a transient error, it usually indicates that the request's input is invalid.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "The API server failed to successfully process the request. While this can be a transient error, it usually indicates that the request's input is invalid.",
        "domain": "youtube.comment",
        "reason": "processingFailure",
        "location": "id",
        "locationType": "parameter"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Nothing changed on my end and i'm wondering if there's an issue with the API or i got restricted in any way
There's nothing to indicate any restrictions applied to my account/project so i suspect its not me.

I'd like to specify that i have an api quota of 500k and it did not get reached. Even now after the reset of the quota, i keep getting the error.

The same when I try to use the API developer (https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/comments/setModerationStatus)

In the past i did get this kind of error, but the requests were processed and the comments were put in the "heldForMorderation" status.

I'm processing a bulk of 80 comments per call.

Answer (score 1):

I am having the same issue with a custom spamfilter that I have written and have also observed that the ability to hide/remove comments is broken in a commercial product (Agorapulse) that I also use.

Neither setmoderationstatus, markasspam or delete are working, basically there is no way to automatically remove the spam comments. (Which is a big problem on my channel)

Basically it looks like something has changed/broken on the API side, as the commands don't succeed even if run directly from the documentation website. (Everything worked fine until about 48hrs ago)

Answer (score 1):

I confirm what has been shared previously.
We encounter some difficulties with markAsSpam, setModerationStatus and delete on youtube#comment domain.

- markAsSpam returns systematically 204 but seems to do nothing
- got same error than @YT Guard with setModerationStatus endpoint (100% errors)
- same as previous point with delete endpoint

I add that I cannot generate 404 anymore with wrong comment ID.
We started to have this error since the November 19th.
Our investigation doesn't reveal anything for the moment, we reproduce with HTTP API requests (Postman) and the online forms 'Try this API' available in reference documentation.